# Discord Bot which can Auto Purge messages at in interval

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I was gonna make a reddit post about this as it seemed a bit more appropriate, but here we go.

So I am trying to make a simple discord bot that with one command, with the arguments `+purge <#channel> <interval>` so I can have a channel with the interval being in seconds, which its messages will be purged automatically. Also one other thing, I would like to have a simple command `+purge stop` so it will stop all purging.

I want to make this simple as I can as I only need this purging process for 1 channel.

**I am not asking anyone deliberately for any code to be done and/or coming off as rude in anyway.**

*What I do want* is for any suggestions of code or on where I could find the resources for this as **I am very new to JavaScipt** and coding in gereral. Any advice on anything about this would be appreciated! :D

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is it that you do not understand? Is it selecting another channel, getting second input? or all of it? This will help be better answer your question.

Comment: @UnRealG Yeah its selecting a channel and getting input from all messages, all input I believe, because its regardless of what the message is or who its from.